# iOS simulator with auth0 ionic/react

Tags: ios, reactjs, ssl, ionic-framework, auth0

Need help with implementing Auth0 with Ionic/React. I've followed this [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic-react/01-login), but have not had any luck with an ios simulator.

http works fine when opening the app in the browser, but if I try and run an ios simulator, it complains that *"auth0-spa-js must run on a secure origin.".*

​

I've tried adding the simulators host and port numbers to the allowed web origins and callback urls in the Auth0 dashboard. I've tried adding a ssl cert from [charles](https://www.detroitlabs.com/how-to-set-up-charles-proxy-for-an-ios-simulator) and I've tried...

```json
ionic cap run ios -l --external --https
```

which starts a server running on https but the ios simulator returns "about:blank" in the developer tools.

Has anyone had any luck with getting Auth0 to work in a simulator?

Comment: I've gotten it to work with Ionic AppAuth and Auth0. https://github.com/wi3land/ionic-appauth/tree/master/demos/react

Comment: Thank you! Opening the app through xcode worked. I am running into an issue with xcode not ready my env variables though, which I had set in the .env file of the react project. Is there a certain way to get xcode to use though env variables?